Identifying/finding slider for casement window operator
I'm trying to identify and replace the small plastic part that's circled in this picture:

It is the small plastic part that connect the metal protruding arm of the casement window operator to the rail on the window side.
Any ideas on how to identify it, and/or source the part?

You might consult the manufacturing website, look up the specific model of window, and find a parts list.

Might get lucky looking at SWISCO.

It's doubtful you'll find just the plastic tab that fits into the track on the window.
However, this is a DIY site. It should not be difficult to cut a thin piece of nylon or polycarbonate to the correct size, and to attach it with an L-bracket and small, countersunk screws.
